# Getting (historical) Standard & Poor Stock Guides

Tags: stock-markets, online-data-source, historical-data, market-data

Chapter 15 of The Intelligent Investor mentions S&P publishes (as of the 1970s) a monthly Stock Guide. Is this still a worthwhile resource? What's the best way to get access to this guide, preferably without paying for it? I currently use Scottrade as my primary broker, do they provide access to this document for their customers?

I'm looking for digital content, going to a library or finding a physical copy would be less than ideal.

Comment: Would love some feedback why this was downvoted; if it's not appropriate or needs more clarification, happy to improve the question.

Comment: When it comes to stock analysis and historical data, it seems that none of the companies out there is willing to provide any kind of data-stream, maybe for quite *obvious* reasons.

Comment: I know exactly what you are talking about. Several years ago I purchased a copy of the s&p stock guide, 2001 (I think), but I bought it in 2012. It was very used but intact. I may have gotten it from Amazon but I have not been able to find another copy or even a more current copy. No one seems to sell them anymore. What baffles me is why not? It was a great tool! Very handy. Sure one can perform individual inquiries on the internet but only if one knows the names of the companies they're researching. If you're searching by some other feature, i.e. Sector, growth rate, p/e, dividends, etc., wel

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen one of these in quite some time. Back in the 1970s, maybe the 1980s, stock brokers would occasionally send their retail clients a complimentary copy once in a while. Also, I remember the local newspaper would offer a year-end edition for a few dollars (maybe $3) and that edition would include the newspaper company's name on the cover. They were very handy little guides measuring 5 1/2 x 8 (horizontal) with one line devoted to each company. They listed hundreds of publicly traded companies and had basic info on each company. As you stated, for further info you needed to go to the library and follow-up with the big S&P and/or Moody's manuals. That was long before the internet made such info available at the click of a button on a home computer!

Answer (score 0):

Log in to your Scottrade account, and goto Markets --> Analyst Views --> Click the PDF link for the company.  Also, there is also the 'Views and News' part of the web page which has additional information beyond what exist in the reports.  [image: screenshot of scottrade analyst view section]